# d3js.data drill down on bound data to current selection for new data array and data key

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a d3 selection that looks like this:

```
var circles = release.selectAll("circle")
                .data(function (d) { return d.values; }, function (d) { return d.key; })
                .enter().append("circle")
```

release have data that looks like this:

```
 [ { key: name, values: [data] }, ...]
```

and I am trying to drill down to the nested [data] array to add svg circles. The above does not work and all it created were 1 circle for the first element in d.values and 1 for d.key. It works if I remove the key function:

```
var circles = release.selectAll("circle")
                .data(function (d) { return d.values; })
                .enter().append("circle")
```

There are no circles to begin with. I am using d3.v3.js version 3.3.8. Any ideas why the key function is not working?

Adding a couple more code section and hope that it helps to show that I have defined a key function earlier when I bound the entire data set.

```
var individual_release = gEnter.selectAll(".individual_release")
                                .data(data, function (d) { return d.key; });
var release = individual_release.enter()
                                .append("g")
```

Comment: Why are you using the key function? The `d` in there would be one of the elements of the array in `d.values` -- do those have a `key` attribute?

Comment: Do the data element in `.values` have `.key` attributes?

Comment: d does not have a key attribute. It has x and y attributes. I was trying to make sure that the set of circles with the same key gets updated. I ran into an issue where they were not updated correctly when I changed the data array.

Comment: If those elements don't have `.key` attributes, you can't use them in the key function. This is why it's not working.

Comment: Added in a `key` attribute to the objects in the values object array and still ran into the same problem. The objects now look like `{key: <value>, x: <value>, y: <value>}` and also added a console.log(d) and confirmed that the object is formatted correctly.

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example please?